# Flutter Firebase auth phone and Firestore database

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I would like when connecting by phone via OTP verification, to know if the account already exists and in this case retrieve its information. But if the account does not exist, create a collection in Firestore database with default information

My functional code for the telephone connection:

```
    class AuthenticateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticateScreenState createState() => _AuthenticateScreenState();
}

class _AuthenticateScreenState extends State<AuthenticateScreen> {
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController otpController = TextEditingController();

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool otpVisibility = false;
  User? user;
  String verificationID = "";
  
  String phoneNumber = "";
  final DocumentReference documentReference =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc("users/{users}");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Phone Auth",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[900],
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: phoneController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Phone Number',
                prefix: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  child: Text('+33'),
                ),
              ),
              maxLength: 10,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            ),
            Visibility(
              child: TextField(
                controller: otpController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'OTP',
                  prefix: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    child: Text(''),
                  ),
                ),
                maxLength: 6,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              visible: otpVisibility,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.indigo[900],
              onPressed: () {
                if (otpVisibility) {
                  verifyOTP();
                } else {
                  loginWithPhone();
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                otpVisibility ? "Verify" : "Login",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void loginWithPhone() async {
    auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: "+33" + phoneController.text,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) {
          print("You are logged in successfully");
        });
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        print(e.message);
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
        otpVisibility = true;
        verificationID = verificationId;
        setState(() {});
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
    );
  }

  void verifyOTP() async {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationID, smsCode: otpController.text);


    await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then(
          (value) {
        setState(()  {
          phoneNumber = phoneController.text;
          print("Connecte avec le compte " + "+33" + phoneController.text,);
          user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

        });
      },
    ).whenComplete(
          () {

        if (user != null) {

          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Vous êtes maintenant connecté",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Blue2Color,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0,
          );
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Home_Screen(),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "La connexion a échoué.",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my old code for login by mail to create a collection on firestore database :

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  AppUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    initUser(user);
    return user != null ? AppUser(user.uid) : null;
  }

  void initUser(User? user) async {
    if(user == null) return;
    NotificationService.getToken().then((value) {
      DatabaseService(user.uid).saveToken(value);
    });
  }

  Stream<AppUser?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result =
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;



      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I propose creating a cloud function which listens to account creation event. In the function you create the record in firestore. Check this for more details https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events .

Comment: And how can I check if the account already exists? Do you have a code to give me? sorry for my english i am french

Comment: I don't understand why you have to check if an account already exists or not. How I see it is you don't even need to bother checking if the account is created because the event itself is for creating an account (it was non existing before).

Comment: I have to create a firestore database collection if the account does not exist. And if it exists, retrieve its information

Comment: When user sign up for your service, your cloud function creates the collection for the user. This btw happens instantaneously (less than 1second). And when a user signs in you retrieve the record from firestore.

Comment: Yes exactly, but I don't know how to code this

Comment: can't really dig code right now. Check the link in the first comment and try to understand how you could use it for your usecase.